# How to install a package rdkit from Conda with pip?

Tags: pip, package, conda, rdkit

I am trying to install rdkit using pip3. But it doesn't work.

```
sudo pip3 install rdkit
Error:  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rdkit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rdkit
```

There is only apparently one option with conda

```
conda install -c rdkit rdkit
```

How can I install it with pip?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just follow their recommendation? http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#installation

Comment: Which is the best way to install rdkit? I tried to install by the command `conda install -c conda-forge rdkit` or `conda install -c rdkit rdkit` but it showed conflict in a new conda environment with python=3.7. I also try to install by pip (`pip install rdkit`), but when I imported in python, it said "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdkit'".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of a week or two ago, you can install `rdkit` using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/rdkit-pypi/)

```
pip install rdkit-pypi
python -c "from rdkit import Chem; print(Chem.MolToMolBlock(Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1CCC1')))"
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rdkit-pypi

Comment: As of 2023, it is much simpler. One can install with pip like : `pip install rdkit`

Comment: Build information and details can be found at the https://github.com/kuelumbus/rdkit-pypi GitHub page. Please open an issue directly at this Github page if you find something not working as expected.

Note: Older versions of RDKit might be available at the rdkit-pypi PyPi repository. rdkit-pypi is the old name of RDKit at PyPi.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install rdkit with pip at the moment, either build from source or install using anaconda as [recommended](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#installation). Making rdkit installable with pip is tricky, see [github issue](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/issues/1812)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
conda create -n rdkit -y # create new environment
conda activate rdkit # activate new environment
conda install -c conda-forge rdkit -y 
conda install -c anaconda openpyxl -y # optional: if there is an openpyxl error
conda install ipykernel -y # optional: It will be useful if you use jupyter
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).