# Installing RDKit using Conda

Tags: python, github, anaconda, rdkit

I have Anaconda installed on my Windows 10 machine.

In Spyder, I tried to install RDKit using the instructions found here: [How to install RDKit with Conda](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/master/Docs/Book/Install.md), but nothing happened when I typed:

```
$ conda create -c conda-forge -n my-rdkit-env rdkit
```

It sort of just hung there.

So, I think it needs to have a channel set, or something similar. I think it doesn't know where to look.  (The version on Anaconda.org seems to be old, so I can't install it from Anaconda.org.)

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Just for clarification: That command does not install from github, but instead installs the package from the `conda-forge` channel, which according to [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rdkit) should be at v2021.03.3.

Comment: Can you calrify what "just hung there" means? At what step does it hang exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the question.  When I issue a command to the interpreter, it either takes an action (say prints something), prints an error, or does nothing.  Then, it gives a new prompt for another command.  In this case, after I hit return, it never gave me a new command line, even after I waited for a long time.  Usually, if it was in the process of doing an install, it would provide some status information while the install was happening.   In this case, literally nothing happened after I hit return.

Comment: It may be that I am using the wrong install command.  Will try more this evening using the commands offered on conda-forge.  Thank you for correcting which channel I was using.

Comment: Okay, I was able to install it using:  conda install -c conda-forge rdkit.  Yay! Except something still isn't working.  RDKit installed.  I can see it there with:  conda list.  But, RDKit instructions aren't being accepted.  Still puzzled.

Comment: Recently, you can install RDKit without conda if this might be an option. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76217512/7295599